# perl DBI SQLite commit or detach fails when AutoCommit is set to false

Tags: sqlite, perl

The following code fails on my Windows 10 machine running Strawberry Perl 5.24:

```
use DBI;

unlink glob("*.db3");
my $source = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=first.db3",q(),q(),{AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError =>1});

# populate source DB
$source->do("CREATE TABLE test(x integer)");
$source->do("INSERT INTO test(x) values (1)");
$source->commit();
$source->disconnect();

# copy source to dest
my $dest = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=second.db3",q(),q(),{AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError =>1});

$dest->do("CREATE TABLE test(x integer)");
$dest->do("ATTACH DATABASE 'first.db3' AS chunk_db");
$dest->do("INSERT INTO test(x) SELECT x FROM chunk_db.test");

# this statement will fail when AutoCommit => 0
$dest->commit;
$dest->do("DETACH DATABASE chunk_db");
$dest->disconnect();
```

To make it work, I have to connect with `AutoCommit => 1` when creating the `$dest` object. Otherwise I'll get the following error message:

```
   DBD::SQLite::db do failed: database chunk_db is locked at test.pl line 21.
```

Is this a bug in DBI or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `unlink "*.db3"` is wrong (unless there is a file literally named `*.db3`). Use `unlink glob("*.db3")` instead.

Comment: @mob . Thanks, fixed

Comment: Line 21 is the DETACH line, which you don't need because the very next thing you do is close the database. Remove that and it works.

Comment: @Shawn Actually, it is just a sample code to show that detach or commit fails. My actual code is more complicated that. The attach / detach statements are inside a loop, which a detach is needed otherwise there will be many databases attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite), when `AutoCommit` mode is turned off:

> The default transaction behavior of SQLite is deferred, that means, locks are not acquired until the first read or write operation, and thus it is possible that another thread or process could create a separate transaction and write to the database after the BEGIN on the current thread has executed, and eventually cause a "deadlock". To avoid this, DBD::SQLite internally issues a BEGIN IMMEDIATE if you begin a transaction by calling begin_work or by turning off AutoCommit (since 1.38_01).
>
> If you really need to turn off this feature for some reasons, set sqlite_use_immediate_transaction database handle attribute to false, and the default deferred transaction will be used.

(This seems like undesirable behavior, and maybe it's because I'm tired but I don't see how you can get deadlocks; just errors when trying to lock a database that's already locked by another connection to it)

But anyways:

```
$ sqlite3 second.db3
sqlite> attach database 'first.db3' as chunk_db;
sqlite> begin immediate;
sqlite> detach database chunk_db;
Error: database chunk_db is locked
```

That looks familiar...

The default behavior when `AutoCommit` is off means you're *always* in a transaction with an acquired [RESERVED lock](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#reserved_lock). This has some unusual side-effects as you're seeing.

So, solutions in my order of preference:

- Turn on `AutoCommit` mode and manually begin transactions (With `$dbh->begin_work`).
- Skip the `DETACH` since you're closing the database connection anyways.
- Leave `AutoCommit` disabled and set the `sqlite_use_immediate_transaction` option to 0 when connecting to the database file.

Comment: Also consider something like [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector), [DBIx::TransactionManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::TransactionManager), or [Mojo::SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::SQLite) which all have features to make transactions nicer to use with AutoCommit enabled.