# sqlite3: detach database produces database is locked error

Tags: sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database open. I attach a second database, check whether the first and second database have the same value in a table, and then detach the second database. The detach command gives the error "database db2 is locked".

The process is not multi-threaded. There are no other processes accessing the databases. I get the same results on NFS and the local disk. I tried inserting a delay before the detach in case the lock mentioned in the error is related to the file system.

If I comment out the SELECT statement in the code below, the detach works. So basically, attach then detach works, but if I execute SQL code before the detach I receive SQLITE_ERROR return status and the error message shown above.

SQLite version 3.22.0.1

BTW, I realize I could SELECT count(s.id) instead of looping over each row returned from SELECT *, but other posts talk about making sure sqlite3_step() is called until SQLITE_DONE is returned and I wanted to try everything before posting here.

```
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *errMsg;
    const char *zLeftover;
    int count = 0;

    // DB declared as:
    // sqlite3 *DB;
    // opened as:
    // sqlite3_open(":memory:", &DB);
    sqlret = sqlite3_exec(DB, "ATTACH DATABASE foo.db AS db2;", NULL, 0, &errMsg);
    assert(sqlret == SQLITE_OK);

    sqlret = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, 
        "SELECT * FROM sessions s INNER JOIN db2.sessions s2 ON s2.id=s.id;",
             -1, &stmt, &zLeftover);
    assert(sqlret == SQLITE_OK);

    sqlret = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    while (sqlret == SQLITE_ROW) {
        ++count;
        sqlret = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    }
    sqlret = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    assert(sqlret == SQLITE_OK);

    sqlret = sqlite3_exec(DB, "DETACH DATABASE db2", NULL, 0, &errMsg);
    // This assert fails with SQLITE_ERROR
    assert(sqlret == SQLITE_OK);
```

I expect the sqlite3_finalize(stmt) call to remove any internal locking on the attached database. Is there another call or additional SQL that must be executed before the detach? A pragma setting? A configuration option on the lib?

I've searched the usual places with no luck. Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: I've seen this before, and IIRC it had to do with not being in [autocommit](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/get_autocommit.html) mode. Are you in the middle of a transaction when detaching the database? (What does `sqlite3_get_autocommit()` return?)

Comment: Heh, [no wonder it sounded familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064603/perl-dbi-sqlite-commit-or-detach-fails-when-autocommit-is-set-to-false). That answer is perl-specific, but the same thing applies - you can't detach a database when in the middle of a transaction.

Comment: sqlite3_get_autocommit() returned 0 and there was a transaction. I've added an "end;" and now sqlite3_get_autocommit() returns 1 after the SELECT and just before the DETACH. I still see the same error when executing the DETACH. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: When `sqlite3_get_autocommit()` is returning 1, detach works fine for me. Add a [mcve], emphasis on the *complete*, that demonstrates it?

Comment: In the process of creating a complete example to submit, I discovered a transaction that was still active. Thanks again for your help.